# Magick .NET MagickDelegateErrorException when attempting to read uploaded .eps file

Tags: .net, delegates, imagemagick, postscript, eps

I'm receiving a MagickDelegateErrorException when trying to perform this action:

```
 public static Image LoadEps(HttpPostedFileBase file)
 {
      MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
      settings.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.RGB;
      settings.Density = new MagickGeometry(300, 300);

      using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage())
      {
          image.AddProfile(ColorProfile.SRGB);
          image.Read(file.InputStream, settings);
          return (Image)image.ToBitmap();
      }
 }
```

The exception message is cryptic:

> Magick: Postscript delegate failed `C:/some/directory/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-14256CekyegnNSk1p': No such file or directory @ error/ps.c/ReadPSImage/840

I've done some googling on this and there are several mentions of GhostScript, but as I understand through Magick documentation, this should work without dependencies other than the Visual C++ libraries.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to install Ghostscript if you want to use Magick.NET to convert EPS files. You can download the installation files from here: http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html.  Make sure you install the version of GhostScript with the same platform. If you use the 64-bit version of Magick.NET you should also install the 64-bit version of Ghostscript. You can use the 32-bit version together with the 64-version but you will get a better performance if you keep the platforms the same.

The [documentation](https://magick.codeplex.com/documentation) has been changed to explain this better.

Comment: Thanks kindly, installing this fixes the issue.